# eliminar registros duplicados específicos en mysql

Tags: mysql, delete

hola quería pedirles ayuda para saber como eliminar registros repetidos específicos en mysql por ejemplo que de la sig tabla

| id | fruta |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | fresa |
| 2 | fresa |
| 3 | manzana |
| 4 | fresa |
| 5 | manzana |
| 6 | manzana |

solo quiero que de los registros repetidos quede la  fresa y la manzana en segunda posición sin especificar los id y al final quede

| id | fruta |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | fresa |
| 5 | manzana |

Lo que yo intente fue

```
DELETE FROM tabla
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT id FROM tabla
    WHERE fruta = 'fresa' and fruta = 'manzana'
    ORDER BY fruta
    LIMIT 1, 999999
  ) t
);
```

pero solo elimina el primero y no el tercero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo siguiente es un código que corre en postgres. Pero segura te da una idea

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
    PARTITION BY
    fruta
    ORDER BY id ASC
) AS row, * 
FROM tablas
) AS duplicados
WHERE duplicados.row > 1;
```

Comment: gracias si me encamino bastante a solucionar el problema

Answer (score 1):

Casi lo tenias, para borrar los campos repetidos tira esta consulta. Suponiendo que la tabla se llama frutas y la columna con los nombres se llama fruta.

```
DELETE FROM frutas 
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id_min
  FROM (
    SELECT MIN(id) AS id_min
    FROM frutas 
    GROUP BY fruta
  ) AS t
);

select * from frutas;
```

Comment: muchas gracias, no me sirvió para lo que quería pero me ayudo a ver otras formas de solucionar este tipo de situaciones